# use case for HazelCast Cache

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to understand [HazelCast Cache](https://hazelcast.com/use-cases/caching/)

I have a distributed environment where the source data needs to be shared among hosts. I am using HazelCast [List](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/list.html) and [Map](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/map.html) to distribute the data.
The source data is keep changing. I can receive up to date data on all hosts via HazelCast List/Map. How HazelCast cache can be used on top of the HazelCast List/Map.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I understood anything of the question. Can you put a few Javadoc links into the question, like what do you mean by Hazelcast Cache? JCache? NearCache? IMap?

Comment: Still not sure what you want to do. Store IList and IMap in JCache?

Comment: Maybe. Is it possibly to get the best of the two? Such on JCache  the result of IList and IMap? so 1) I get the latest data 2) use Cache? Or it has to be either one of them but not both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hazelcast JCache is a data structure on its own, like IMap and IList. There is no connection between them.

The IMap has its own (local) cache called Near Cache, if you want to reduce the network traffic. Please have a look at the Near Cache documentation for IMap and see if this matches your requirements.

I think there is no such mechanism for IList though.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Near Cache document says "Near cache breaks the strong consistency guarantees; you might be reading stale data." Although 90% of my access is read. Because of this warning, I fear I will get stale data, I still can't use Near Cache. Is that true? Also, it says by default "Each map.get(k) will be a remote operation", is it also true hazelcastinstance.getList(k) operation?

Comment: In fact, my use case is there is a host that does write, all rest hosts do read. Since the data is changing sometimes, I still concerned "Near Cache" would cause reader to get stale data. Is my concern valid?

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply.  

The data in the Near Cache can be stale for a certain amount of time. That's the trade-off for having a cache. In Hazelcast 3.8 we improved the consistency guarantees for the Near Cache to "eventual consistent". So there is a repair mechanism which will eventually fix any stale data in rare edge cases like lost partitions.  

Furthermore you can use a TTL on your Near Cache data, so you can define the maximum "staleness window" of your cached data.